# How to add other dll file into project deloyed into iis server (2012) IN netcore

Tags: asp.net-core

i hava idea but not how to do.
I have website base (used netcore MVC controller-model-view) deloyed into IIS.
I write 1 modun (eg page AboutMe ). I wanna it can install into my web as wordpress or DNN).
this modun was project independent with website was deploy (it only used public library) into webserver.
Do you hava any idea for me. thaks all

Answer (score 0):

I was try Nop ( Ope source) but create modun in this add this main project. that make your project very large becaurse have many modun not need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).